# How to distinguish between 'really' unanswered questions between 'abandoned'- or 'invalid'- or 'forgot to close'-unanswered questions?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, search

Taking the risk of crossposting, I would like to express a main blocker to me for using Stack Overflow (besides that I really think SO is awesome!):

Sorting by unanswered questions also returns questions, which were simply abandoned/not closed/not moderated yet, etc.

I think there must be a way to distinguish that in order to get results of 'really' unanswered questions.

I would love to see a possibility to mark the abandoned items in a way they stay out of the unanswered results.

F.e. allow personal tagging for SO-users and custom creation of result lists (trac-like) would be lovely, than I could create a list 'show all unanswered questions, but not the ones I personal-tagged as crap'.

Can you (the responsible people who can decide about features) let me know, if you are planning something like that or if there are other approaches to get sharper results?

Comment: You'll have to help clean up the list by close-voting/flagging questions that need to be closed, answering questions you can answer and indexing content by quality through voting. If enough of us do this, we can alleviate the problem.

Comment: Hi downvoters/moderators, I wanted to flag'n'close my quest as a dup, but cannot find one :-) If, I get the answers right, there won't be tagging-possibilities and curations of quests is expected, that answers my quest. The deletion of posts seems critical to me, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up injecting a user-script in my browser, which removes posts of the list, by a given array of post-nrs. In case anyone's interested:
https://github.com/ida/skriptz/blob/6ff514be53451822794ed66aa06f5921f071a51f/stackoverflow_filter.user.js

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you'll get to get a list like this, is to sort the [Unanswered Questions list by votes.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes).

Remember, any question with even one upvote on an answer will no longer be considered 'unanswered' by the system for the purposes of this list. So if you see an 'abandoned' question with an unupvoted answer, you can upvote that answer to remove it from the list. As your reputation grows, you'll gain access to the tools you need to remove the other ones as you come across them, (closure, deletion, etc.).

Comment: Thank you LPMF, but what, if there is no question worth upvoting? And do you by any chance know, if there are plans for features such as personal tagging?

Answer (score 0):

As [this other answer says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156973/152859), voting for questions is what you're looking for. Sufficiently neglected and downvoted questions [will also be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) in the end.

So, in my opinion the issue you had is one of insufficient curation of old/unanswered questions. In the tags I know, a mix of downvoting, answering and closure/flagging is needed. To get more people do this work, I [proposed a gold badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268).

Comment: Hi Nemo, thanks for your feedback. Yes, looks like my mistake is, to not downvote and/or flag so much, I really don't like to do it :-)