# Closing a question because you are not familiar with the topic

Tags: discussion

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860320/worklight-5-0-5-1-cannot-drag-and-drop-to-the-rich-page-editor-at-all

Was closed due to: "closed as not a real question by Will♦ 6 hours ago
It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ."

Will, who closed the question is apparently not familiar with the topic at hand, but other users who replied in comments, are familiar with the question at hand.

So, just because a person is not familiar with the topic, is that an actual valid reason to close a question...?

Comment: It's a list of statements. None of them adding up to a question

Comment: Questions end with the character `"?"`.

Comment: @IdanAdar - It doesn't take fluency in English to a) understand the difference between a declarative sentence and a question and b) understand that questions in English end with a question mark.

Comment: @IdanAdar, I think the best solution to borderline or neglected questions is to give a good answer in time. That's particularly important IMHO for the old unanswered questions, which few people (like you) care about. I also proposed a gold badge for that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I disagree - the question you've linked to isn't really a question - note the complete lack of any question marks. It looks more like a bug report, which is definitely not in Stack Overflow's purview.

To boot, it isn't really a programming question, so it's also off-topic for the site, and perhaps that would have been a better descriptor for closing the question.

Either way, it doesn't require domain-specific knowledge to analyse the question for its suitability for Stack Overflow in this way.

In the theoretical case where a moderator *has* wrongfully closed a question, with enough reputation you can vote to reopen the question. You can also always flag the question and type in something in the 'other' field, for example 'Shouldn't have been closed because...'.

Comment: Good answer. There's always reopen, for when the mod *was* wrong, but this decision was right.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, that question is not a question at all. There is not answerable, solvable problem, no question statement, nothing. That question is a bug report and a bunch of statements, not a question. @Will was perfectly right in closing it.