# Close vote queue reduction: Add click to Ask Question

Tags: feature-request

To confirm the question is appropriate ask question askers to choose one or more of:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

As described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Some may realize they were on the wrong site.

Comment: The "ask question" process for new users is already littered with so many hints, confirmation dialogs, FAQ links... it's unlikely that adding *another* signpost is going to change things.

Comment: I suspect most off topic question posters would just select any box in order to proceed. Meta insists questions are tagged. Discussion/bug/feature request and still gets loads of programming questions.

Comment: But they are mostly bugs @Martin :-).

Comment: "Ah, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I want a recommendation for a good game engine. That's a pretty specific problem, and of course a tool commonly used by game programmers. Practically answering that one should be no issue"

Comment: @probablyPekka While true; clicking ok without reading seems to be ingrained in humans (grumble grumble) but choosing an option without reading isn't yet so prevalent

Comment: One way to address the close queue, however drastic, is automatic deletion by downvoting of old questions. Such cleanup can be encouraged by adding a gold badge for those who go through the backlog of ancient unanswered questions (distinguishing the good from the bad). http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268

Answer (score 3):

I think there are already many defenses at the initial, Asking, point. And none is intrusive, only some alerts about the title, content and tags. As I understand it, *registration is only required* in this Meta and Stack Overflow. And that's about it, nothing more, go and Ask.

IMO any intrusive resistance is futile because the [input field for the Question title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) already has:

> [image: hello, programming question?]

That doesn't prevent, ***at all***, questions about Career Advice or more exotic stuff.

---

I've [answered a similar Q](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7689/require-suggest-informed-badge-for-asking-questions) at Meta Ask Ubuntu. Its main site has the following in the input field:

> ```
> What's your Ubuntu question? Be specific.
> ```

[*Ubuntu*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28disambiguation%29) has ***zero*** relation with Chemistry, that didn't prevent someone asking about Atoms & elements...

> [image: unbelievable as it is. hello, Ubuntu?]

---

The cherry on the cake goes to someone asking a **Microsoft** question at Ask Different (Apple) that kindly reminds us on *the very **first field:*** `What's your Apple hardware or software question?`

[image: hello, pears?]

---

We are doomed to receive blind asking folks from all over at increasingly alarming rates.
The force is in self-moderation. I think the problem lies on the Close Vote Queue and that's [being tackled at this very moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208311).